# Is there a formula that will paste the result of a separate formula as a value?

Tags: excel, formula, paste

Ex.

column A is a formula that outputs an 8 digit ID from a prior delimited calculation. I want to vlookup that ID to a separate set of data, but it is not finding the ID when the lookup value is part of a formula. 
Is there a way to paste the formula result as a value in column b?

I have a list of 3000+ IDs, so using the F2, F9 trick won't work, since I would have to do that cell by cell.

Would prefer not to use VBA, but if that is the only way, can someone help simplify that process (new to using VBA)

Comment: Is the ID all numbers or is it alphanumeric? I say this because the issue could be the data that is in the cell with the formula result.  Without knowing what your data looks like or what formula you are using to determine the lookup value I can't help much more.

Comment: **Help us to help you.** Please update your question with a specific example.

Comment: see the [`Value`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VALUE-function-257D0108-07DC-437D-AE1C-BC2D3953D8C2) formula or [`Text`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20D5AC4D-7B94-49FD-BB38-93D29371225C) formula. They may help (but can't be sure as, like others have said, you didn't provide any sample data).

Comment: the IDs are numeric. The formula is taking a large strand of a ID and uses a left function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in column A based on a left function of a bunch of numbers, and just want that result in column B, all you have to do is put:

```
=Value(ColRow)
```

in Column B. Then you can look up the value in Column B via `VLookUp`.

I am an avid Excel user and personally tested this solution. Though it appears @Scott beat me to it in the comment section.